# Когда следует голосовать?

Tags: поддержка, faq

- Когда следует голосовать за вопрос:

  - Какими качествами должен обладать вопрос, чтобы заслуживать голоса «за»?
  - Когда не следует голосовать за вопрос?
  - По каким причинам вопрос может заслуживать голоса «против»?
  - Как именно голосовать против вопроса: нужно ли немного подождать, чтобы дать его автору шанс исправить его или надо голосовать сразу же?
  - Когда не следует голосовать против вопроса?
- Когда следует голосовать за ответ:

  - Какими качествами должен обладать ответ, чтобы заслуживать голоса «за»?
  - Когда не следует голосовать за ответ?
  - По каким причинам ответ может заслуживать голоса «против»?
  - Как именно голосовать против ответа: нужно ли немного подождать, чтобы дать его автору шанс исправить его или надо голосовать сразу же?
  - Когда не следует голосовать против ответа?
- Когда следует голосовать за комментарий:

  - Поскольку голосование за комментарии не влияет на репутацию, новым участникам было бы полезно понимать, зачем вообще нужно голосовать за комментарии.

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046/274323)».</sub>

Comment: Что, разве не "как душе угодно" и "как велит сердце"? :)

Answer (score 7):

Учтите, что голосование – субъективно. Ниже приведена лишь «шпаргалка» по голосованию.

> ### Коротко
>
> Чтобы определиться, как оценить сообщение, следует задать себе вопрос «помогает ли оно сайту?». В случае положительного ответа, проголосовать за, в случае отрицательного – против.

Для только что запущенных сайтов: будьте менее критичны, особенно если на сайте не так уж много сообщений с высоким рейтингом. Сообществу нужно большое количество участников с высокими привилегиями, и отдавать голос за «неплохой, но не выдающийся» вопрос вполне допустимо.

Постарайтесь, чтобы второстепенные факторы, например, текущий рейтинг вопроса, а также другие ответы, не влияли на ваше решение. Иногда участник видит сообщение с множеством голосов «против» и из солидарности, не разобравшись, также голосует «против». Так делать не стоит. Аналогично, на вас не должна оказывать влияние личность автора сообщения или его репутация. Любое сообщение от участника с высокой репутацией следует оценивать с той же критичностью, что и сообщение от участника с репутацией 1 балл. Знатоки также могут совершать ошибки. Голос «против» и критический комментарий – это именно то, что вы должны сделать, встретив на сайте некачественное сообщение, *независимо от личности автора*.

Существует и другая крайность: [«голосование в качестве компенсации»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137315/downvoting-average-mass-upvote-question). При этом участник голосует так, чтобы сообщение заняло достойное, с его точки зрения, место в рейтинге (например, голосуя против посредственных рядом сообщений с высоким рейтингом и т.п.). Так делать не следует. При голосовании старайтесь не учитывать текущий рейтинг сообщения.

### Вопрос

Голосуя против вопроса, делайте это сразу же, не дожидаясь исправлений. Если вопрос нуждается в улучшении, прокомментируйте это и голосуйте против. Если вопрос будет улучшен, вы всегда сможете [аннулировать свой голос](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

#### Голос «за»

1. Ясная и четкая формулировка, видна проработка вопроса.
2. Вопрос уникален и/или феноменален.
3. Вопрос полезен для сообщества.
4. Это первый вопрос нового участника, который удовлетворяет всем стандартам качества сообщества, даже если вопрос нельзя назвать выдающимся.

#### Голос «против»

1. Вопрос имеет неясную, непонятную формулировку.
2. Публикация отмечена меткой наподобие [помогите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5), автор не смог проставить адекватные метки.
3. Вопрос слишком «узкий» (скорее всего, для сообщества он будет бесполезен).

Как дополнение, вероятно, следует голосовать за *вопросы*, если в ответах на них содержится ценная информация.

Не надо голосовать против вопроса, если:

1. В вопросе нарушены правила грамматики (но смысл понятен).
2. В вопросе содержится плохой (но ясный) код; в вопросе использована неудачная стратегия написания кода; сама идея программы неверна.

**Помните, цель голосования – отсеять некачественные *сообщения*, а не *код* или *автора*.** Кроме того, в сообщениях допускается использовать *всё*, [даже `eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).

### Ответ

Голосуйте за ответы сразу, комментируйте и аннулируйте отрицательный голос при появлении исправлений. Будьте более лояльны к новичкам – комментируйте, а голос «против» отдавайте только если они к вам не прислушиваются.

#### Голос «за»

1. Ответ ясен и понятен.
2. В ответе содержится достаточное объяснение основной идеи автора ответа.
3. В ответе нет прямого ответа на «как», но ясно описано «почему».

#### Голос «против»

При выставлении отрицательного голоса старайтесь комментировать свое решение.

1. Ответ не отвечает на поставленный вопрос. Вы можете также отметить его тревогой, при необходимости.
2. Ответ не несет смысловой нагрузки.
3. Ответ вида [«Самый быстрый стрелок на Западе»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite-on-mso), опубликованный «на скорость», но почти не содержащий ценной информации.
4. Ответ, который содержит только код: публикация *должна* приносить пользу *Людям Из Будущего*™. Второго такого кода – как и второго такого вопроса – может не быть ([хотя, как знать](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)). *Людям Из Будущего*™ нужно объяснить, *почему* код плохой/хороший/и т.п., чтобы они что-то из этого вынесли.
5. [Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) [представляет собой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) [гиперссылку](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question/7659#7659).
6. Ответ неверен (по вашему мнению).
7. Ответ описывает неправильную стратегию кодирования. В отличие от вопросов, ответы должны содержать только правильный код. Таким образом, *качество сообщения* в случае вопросов и ответов определяется по-разному. Качество вопроса состоит главным образом *не в качестве кода*, а в сути самого вопроса. А вот для ответов, неправильный код – не есть хорошо. В случае, если кроме плохого кода в ответе есть хорошее объяснение – голосуйте «против», комментируйте, аннулируйте голос «против» при появлении исправлений. Или воздержитесь и от голосования, и от комментариев. Подходят оба варианта.

Не голосуйте против только потому, что:

1. Автор – ваш «воображаемый соперник». Голосование придумано для улучшения *качества содержимого сайта*, а несправедливое голосование вредит системе. Кроме того, голосование против конкурирующих ответов – это [неспортивно](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/119/sportsmanship).
2. Грамматика. Если вопрос нарушает грамматические правила, но понятен, не стоит голосовать против него.

### Комментарии

Голосование за комментарии, по сути, не имеет значения. Помните: когда у публикации масса комментариев, видны будут те, за которые голосуют. Поэтому, если комментарий повышает качество вопроса/помогает автору, за него нужно проголосовать.

Comment: Шутку про eval не понял )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну вроде как если речь зашла про `eval()`, то ничего хорошего не предвидится. Только [tag:непонятная-каша-из-веба]

Comment: А что значит "слишком узкий вопрос"? Слишком специфичная тема, в которой разбираются очень немногие? Можете привести пример?

Comment: @Sam Слишком узкий в нашем понимании – это вопрос, описываемый такую проблему, которая никогда ни у кого более не встретиться. Такой вопрос не несет пользы сообществу.