# Подпись общего сообщения

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, общие-сообщения

Подпись под общим сообщением сейчас выглядит [примерно так](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4049/176217):

> [image: общее]

Оригинальная английская [строка в transifex такая](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/108334544?key=26459b8c977c85b8e8a6493dd094154a):

> $RevisionCount$ revs, $AuthorCount$ users $TopUserPercentage$%$br$$TopUserName$

В текущей версии, как мне кажется, имеются изъяны:

- отсутствие запятой после "участника"
- указание процентов и имени на разных строках

Исправлять оба эти пункта одновременно считаю излишним. Поэтому предлагаю рассмотреть предложенные варианты в ответах.

Замечу, что строки ведут на разные ссылки: первая строка на список ревизий, вторая на профиль участника. Т.е. чтобы новый вариант работал (если мы решим вообще что-то менять) надо оставить в тексте один перевод строки, т.е. `$br$`.

Если ничего менять не хотим - голосуйте против вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю переставить процент после имени:

> [image: пример]

Вариант утверждён на transifex. Увидеть в действии можно будет, скорее всего, в ближайший понедельник.

Фактически получилось не совсем так как ожидалось. Значение с процентами не кликабельно и отображается другим цветом:

> [image: факт]

Comment: Какое-то всё синее...

Comment: @alexolut, потому что [не с меты](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454684/178988) скрин)

Comment: Надо `Миша 2%` и `Чуров 146%` в скринах сделать. Может активность голосующих повысится :)

Comment: @alexolut, о, голоса появились. Когда я последний раз смотрел, были везде нолики)

Comment: Пару дней уже как.

Comment: [Как вам?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35851484#35851484)

Comment: @alexolut, молодец! круто!

Answer (score 1):

Переносим проценты на вторую строку:

> [image: проценты]

Comment: Стоит заметить, что строка `88% Nicolas Chabanovsky` будет в этом случае вести на профиль со 100% содержанием Nicolas Chabanovsky. Надеюсь, такой "налог" не будет считаться неподъёмным :)

Comment: А если переставить 88% в конец?

Comment: @Qwertiy то можно оформить отдельным ответом :)

Comment: [Готово](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4850/178988)

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавляем запятую:

> [image: запятая]

Этот вариант плох тем, что при увеличении кол-ва редакций/участников, проценты переедут на новую строку, кол-во строк визуально станет 3. Как это выглядит сейчас на одном из ответов:

> [image: 3 строки]

При таком раскладе запятая в конце первой строки будет смотреться не очень хорошо.