# Слетел перевод статуса для общего сообщения

Tags: дефект, локализация, общие-сообщения

Собственно, [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6940/176217):

> [image: revs/users]

Следует вернуть к [прежнему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4850/176217) виду.

Comment: Спасибо! Записал в задачки. Как наберется несколько аналогичных задача, поправлю все разом.

Comment: Зачем записывать? Можно же поиском найти по мете. К тому же, перевод может исправить и кто-то другой. Правда, насколько я помню, чтобы эти строки обновились надо еще какой-то скрипт разработческий пошевелить.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky кажется, требуются дополнительные действия.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky набралось?

Answer (score 1):

Подхватил старые переводы.

Появятся после обновления базы и пересборки сайта. Пинайте ответственных сотрудников компании, если что.

Comment: Эм. Долго ещё ждать?

Comment: @Suvitruf мотороллер не мой